# ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found and ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run `myApp.xcodeproj` in Xcode on my Phone, and I get the following errors:

> 1. ERROR Internal navigation rejected - `<allow-navigation>` not set for `url='about:blank'`
> 2. ERROR: Start Page at `'www/index.html'` was not found.

The app builds successfully in VSCode, I just cannot run it on my phone in XCode.

I have already tried the following:
- Installing the latest version of Cordova, Ionic
- Used `<allow-navigation href="*" />` in both `config.xml` files

I expect this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, `ionic cordova platform adds ios` will only download the needed tools for iOS.

To build the www directory, run `ionic cordova prepare ios` after adding the platform.

According to the docs, ionic cordova prepare ios does the following:

> Perform an Ionic build, which compiles web assets to www/. Copy the
>   www/ directory into your Cordova platforms. Transform config.xml into
>   platform-specific manifest files. Copy icons and splash screens from
>   resources/ to into your Cordova platforms. Copy plugin files into
>   specified platforms.